# Axis2 ver. 1.5.4 Connection Timeout seems not working

Tags: java, apache-axis, settimeout, webservice-client

My Axis2 service client *ConnectionTimeout* is lasting **too long** [about 60 seconds] when validation team stresses the application by disconnecting the webservices server, even when using next code:

```
serviceClient.getOptions().setProperty(HTTPConstants.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, 1000);
serviceClient.getOptions().setProperty(HTTPConstants.SO_TIMEOUT, 5000);
```

My Axis2 components versions are:

```
axis2: 1.5
axis2-transport-http: 1.5.4
axis2-transport-local: 1.5.4
wsdl4j [if useful]: 1.6.2
```

Is it no longer used?

Thanks in advance, kind regards.

Comment: I think this is a bug. When comparing 1.5.4 and 1.6 versions of class/method `AbstractHTTPender.executeMethod`, version 1.5.4 doesn't define/call the method `setTimeouts(msgContext, method)` just before the HostConfiguration is retrieved to socket factory.

Comment: 1.6.2 tries have been worst, now OperationClient is missing axisConfiguration on second calls. Only the first call is working... any clue would be appreciated.

Comment: ConfigurationContext class in version 1.6.2 differs from 1.5.4 in that the former now assigns `this.axisConfiguration = null` on `terminate()` method, which is invoked when calling `ServiceClient.cleanup()`. This is a legacy system, so I'll remove cleanup invokation and pray.

Comment: Version 1.6.2 doesn't seem to fix CONNECTION_TIMEOUT issue yet. That parameter was set at HttpMethod instance's parameter, though in the very moment to try to connect through the socket it's looking for that parameter at HttpConnection instance's parameters, to which it was never propagated into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I figured out that was wrong regarding this issue was the place where I placed the *CACHED_HTTP_CLIENT* parameter:

**Incorrect** code:

```
serviceClient.getOptions().setProperty(HTTPConstants.CACHED_HTTP_CLIENT, httpClient);
```

**Correct** code:

```
ConfigurationContext axisContext;
try {
    axisContext = ConfigurationContextFactory.createDefaultConfigurationContext();
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new AxisFault(e.getMessage());
}
axisContext.setProperty(HTTPConstants.CACHED_HTTP_CLIENT, httpClient);
stub = new MyStub(axisContext, url);
```

[Axis2 1.5.1 connections management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19187341/axis2-1-5-1-connections-management/19187342#19187342)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, this issue was solved by downgrading Axis2 version. My last pom is pointing at next component versions:

```
axis2: 1.4.1
axis2-adb: 1.4.1
axis2-transport-http: 1.5
axis2-transport-local: 1.5
wsdl4j: 1.4
```

I hope this monologue helps somebody.
Kind regards.

P. S. I'll keep track of Axis2 1.7 in case I can help them with this simple issue.

Comment: After some version changes, it's still not working even with versions stated in my answer... still researching

Comment: Some seconds ago I just realized that next parameter is disturbing the ConnectionTimeout parameter: HTTPConstants.REUSE_HTTP_CLIENT